Sign in oAuthCallback Error in next js 14 or above using google providers
I am creating sign in functionality using Next-Auth with google providers i have created a dropdown menu in this menu user will be able to click and then click on sign-in button. it redirects to api/auth/signin?callbackUrl=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2F where user selects the sign in with goole after clicking sign-in with google it leads to email and password verification page. where user enters email and password after verification it didn't redirect to my application and shows errors. here are the errors
GET /api/auth/providers 200 in 30ms
 GET /api/auth/signin?callbackUrl=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2F 200 in 33ms
 POST /api/auth/signin/google 302 in 1211ms
[next-auth][error][OAUTH_CALLBACK_ERROR] 
https://next-auth.js.org/errors#oauth_callback_error JWT expired, now 1715240896, exp 1715201013 {
  error: RPError: JWT expired, now 1715240896, exp 1715201013
      at Client.validateJWT (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/openid-client/lib/client.js:864:23)     
      at Client.validateIdToken (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/openid-client/lib/client.js:651:64) 
      at Client.callback (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/openid-client/lib/client.js:430:24)        
      at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
      at async oAuthCallback (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/next-auth/core/lib/oauth/callback.js:109:16)
      at async Object.callback (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/next-auth/core/routes/callback.js:52:11)
      at async AuthHandler (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/next-auth/core/index.js:208:28)
      at async NextAuthRouteHandler (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/next-auth/next/index.js:69:28)  
      at async NextAuth._args$ (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/next-auth/next/index.js:105:16)      
      at async C:\Next\ecommerce-yt\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-route.runtime.dev.js:6:53446
      at async e_.execute (C:\Next\ecommerce-yt\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-route.runtime.dev.js:6:44747)
      at async e_.handle (C:\Next\ecommerce-yt\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-route.runtime.dev.js:6:54700)
      at async doRender (C:\Next\ecommerce-yt\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-server.js:1377:42)
      at async cacheEntry.responseCache.get.routeKind (C:\Next\ecommerce-yt\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-server.js:1587:40)
      at async DevServer.renderToResponseWithComponentsImpl (C:\Next\ecommerce-yt\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-server.js:1507:28)
      at async DevServer.renderPageComponent (C:\Next\ecommerce-yt\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-server.js:1924:24)
      at async DevServer.renderToResponseImpl (C:\Next\ecommerce-yt\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-server.js:1962:32)
      at async DevServer.pipeImpl (C:\Next\ecommerce-yt\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-server.js:920:25)  
      at async NextNodeServer.handleCatchallRenderRequest (C:\Next\ecommerce-yt\node_modules\next\dist\server\next-server.js:272:17)
      at async DevServer.handleRequestImpl (C:\Next\ecommerce-yt\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-server.js:816:17)
      at async C:\Next\ecommerce-yt\node_modules\next\dist\server\dev\next-dev-server.js:339:20
      at async Span.traceAsyncFn (C:\Next\ecommerce-yt\node_modules\next\dist\trace\trace.js:154:20)
      at async DevServer.handleRequest (C:\Next\ecommerce-yt\node_modules\next\dist\server\dev\next-dev-server.js:336:24)
      at async invokeRender (C:\Next\ecommerce-yt\node_modules\next\dist\server\lib\router-server.js:174:21)  
      at async handleRequest (C:\Next\ecommerce-yt\node_modules\next\dist\server\lib\router-server.js:353:24) 
      at async requestHandlerImpl (C:\Next\ecommerce-yt\node_modules\next\dist\server\lib\router-server.js:377:13)
      at async Server.requestListener (C:\Next\ecommerce-yt\node_modules\next\dist\server\lib\start-server.js:141:13) {
    name: 'OAuthCallbackError',
    code: undefined
  },
  providerId: 'google',
  message: 'JWT expired, now 1715240896, exp 1715201013'
}
 GET /api/auth/callback/google?state=WbD1LDf6r0mseWQw3LNo9BWSxlc38QT6L3ZDbe29GvY&code=4%2F0AdLIrYdC9MZFw5WH9ZlesxYhtcDRf7-XRN0rNEwSRZraX_9gUGYwdGe7YJ-6Y9ySbLeHcw&scope=email+profile+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.email+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.profile+openid&authuser=0&prompt=none 302 in 1890ms
 GET /api/auth/error?error=OAuthCallback 302 in 42ms
 GET /api/auth/signin?error=OAuthCallback 200 in 31ms

here is my code work 1. UserMenuButton.tsx code
"use client"
import { Session } from 'next-auth'
import { signIn, signOut } from 'next-auth/react'
import Image from 'next/image'
import React from 'react'
interface UserMenuButtonProps{
    session:Session | null
}
const UserMenuButton = ({ session }: UserMenuButtonProps) => {
    const user = session?.user;
  return (
      <div className='dropdown dropdown-end'>
          <label tabIndex={0} className='btn btn-ghost btn-circle'>
              {user ? <Image src={user?.image || "abc"} alt={user?.email || "user email"} height={40} width={40} className='w-10 rounded-full'/> :   <svg
            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
            fill="none"
            viewBox="0 0 24 24"
            className="inline-block h-5 w-5 stroke-current"
          >
            <path
              strokeLinecap="round"
              strokeLinejoin="round"
              strokeWidth="2"
              d="M5 12h.01M12 12h.01M19 12h.01M6 12a1 1 0 11-2 0 1 1 0 012 0zm7 0a1 1 0 11-2 0 1 1 0 012 0zm7 0a1 1 0 11-2 0 1 1 0 012 0z"
            />
          </svg>}
          </label>
          <ul tabIndex={0} className='dropdown-content menu rounded-box menu-sm z-30 mt-3 w-52 bg-base-100 p-2 shadow'>
              <li>{ user ? <button onClick={()=>signOut({callbackUrl:"/"})}>Sign Out</button>: <button onClick={()=>signIn()}>Sign In</button>}</li>
          </ul>
    </div>
  )
}

export default UserMenuButton

route.tsx file code
import prisma from "@/lib/db/prisma";
import { env } from "@/lib/env";
import { PrismaAdapter } from "@auth/prisma-adapter";
import { NextAuthOptions } from "next-auth";
import { Adapter } from "next-auth/adapters";
import NextAuth from "next-auth/next";
import GoogleProvider from "next-auth/providers/google";

export const authOptions: NextAuthOptions = {
  adapter: PrismaAdapter(prisma) as Adapter,
  providers: [
    GoogleProvider({
      clientId: env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
    }),
  ],
  // ... other NextAuth options
  events: {
    async signIn({ user }) {
      // Perform any user-related actions after successful sign-in (e.g., database updates)
      // Ensure this logic is optimized and doesn't introduce significant delays
      console.log("User signed in:", user);
      // ...
    },
  },
  // ... other NextAuth options (e.g., session)
};

const handler = NextAuth(authOptions);
export { handler as GET, handler as POST };

